# Generated typescript dtos use angle bracket assertion

Tags: typescript, servicestack

We are generating our DTOs using the provided Typescript ServicStack reference tool but it is resulting in eslint warnings.

The lint rule that is failing is no-angle-bracket-type-assertion, refer to this for some details: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-angle-bracket-type-assertion/

I could disable the rule and suppress this, but this introduces ambiguity as outlined here https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html so it is recommended to use the new syntax.

Currently they generate using the angle bracket syntax (the ):

```
public constructor(init?:Partial<ResponseError>) { (<any>Object).assign(this, init); }
```

But they should be using the 'as any' syntax:

```
public constructor(init?:Partial<ResponseError>) { (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
```

Does anyone know how to change the generated DTOs or ignore just this one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're [both valid TypeScript syntax for Type Assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions). Palintir doesn't decide what's valid syntax (that's what TypeScript compiler does), they just set some overridable defaults which you can change.

Anyway from the latest [v5.5.1 of ServiceStack that's now on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) it adopts the tslint `(Object as any)` default.